# I need help for my IF condition with multiple conditions in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements

So I need to add the text  "| S  " if column D4 contains more than 0. which I got, but leave the cell blank if Column A has the text "PR" and Column E has the text "68E"

=IF(D4>0,"|   S   ","")

Comment: not eactly pr.  it will say 8090PR or 343PRR

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
=IF(A4="PR","",IF(E4="68E","",D4>0,"| S ","")))
```

Essentially just adds a nested if statement to check PR first followed by whether column D is greater than 0.

The alternative is using the OR operator like so:

```
=IF(OR(A4="PR",E4="68E"),"",IF(D4>0,"| S ",""))
```

Comment: it say error, i entered too many arguments in this function.  i'm running 2007 excel. if that matters?

Comment: thank you so much, glad someone is still awake around this time.  but what is column A: 1032PR it's not exactly PR. but can it be <>"PR"